# Length of insulated copper line set for a central air conditioner

Tags: central-air

How long can a insulated copper line set for a central air conditioner be outside the home?  Is there any problem with it being as much as 10 ft.?

Comment: It varies by make and model.  Please give specifics.

Comment: 10 feet isn't all that long. It's common to have the condenser beside the house, and the line set from there up to the attic level, and horizontally over to the air handler. That's the case at my house, so I'd estimate 25 feet or more. 8 feet for each of two floors, plus at least 10 feet over to the air handler. (comment instead of answer, since I don't know the actual limits)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific unit. Some mini-splits I've looked at can do 50 feet (tube length), and 30 feet of elevation difference. What your specific unit can have depends on your specific unit.

Comment: I have seen large units with long line sets. The factory charge was not enough but with added Freon the system worked fine.